# Solenoid valve driver circuit

Tags: arduino, solenoid, powermosfet

Which extra protection components should i use if my solenoid valve of rating 24V 1.7A is driven by the POWER MOSFET IRF540 controlled by Arduino? (Flywheeling diode is there.)

Comment: What gate voltage are you driving it with? The IRF540 might not even begin turning on until it reaches 4V.

Comment: What do you want to protect? Is your supply correctly fused to suit the wiring?

Comment: @Finbarr I am using Arduino Uno digital pins so the gate pulse voltage is 4.8v to 5v. And I have initially tested the triggering of MOSFET and it is working fine. And IRF540 is selected due to its gate threshold voltage.

Comment: @Kartman by protecting means I have faced the issue of burn out of IRF540 and also the voltage regulator IC 7812 for powering Arduino(supply for Solenoid Valve and Arduino is taken from the same source). So is there any need of placing the protection diode for regulator IC and MOSFET?

Comment: @Kartman I know the issue of back EMF from the solenoid valve so the freewheeling diode is placed in parallel and in reverse biased with the solenoid valve. But other than these any suggestions?

Comment: Worst case, IRF540 will conduct only a 0.25mA at 4V gate voltage. It is a marginal part for this application. If the Arduino is powered via USB, its digital output voltages can be as low as 4.4V. This potentially won't turn on the mosfet enough to draw 2A through it, with the coil in series. Use a different part.

Comment: @Meet_1605 The N-channel mosfet's body diode does the job of a freewheeling diode in this case, so there's no need for an additional diode. The protection you need is proper layout since the ground circuit parasitic inductances can potentially destroy the Arduino.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Thanks for your suggestion but I have checked myself with the DMM the output voltage of the Arduino and it is 4.88V which I think is sufficient for triggering MOSFET. And also the current passing through the Drain-Source of MOSFET is 1.7-1.9A which is also tested by DMM.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica, when I implemented the whole circuit on breadboard the perfect results were obtained but when I transferred it on a general-purpose PCB by soldering, it malfunctioned.

Comment: `I have checked myself with the DMM the output voltage of the Arduino and it is 4.88V which I think is sufficient for triggering MOSFET` Just because you think something's true doesn't make it true. A MOSFET is not 'triggered', at low gate voltages it's weakly on, and ready to cook if not turned on enough. Different MOSFETs, even from same part number and batch, can have different threshold voltages, so one build may sort of work, and another may cook. Use a 'logic level' FET which is properly on with only a few volts.

Comment: @Neil_UK I am not just thinking that it will be true, I have said that I have checked myself in the laboratory that the MOSFET is being properly triggered and the current of 1.7A is flowing through the MOSFET source-drain.

Comment: @Meet_1605  I'm a moderator. @Neil)UK's advice is good but could have been put very slightly more gently. You literally said that you thought xxx and he commented on that. [HERE](https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/okmhn9v08g/MOTOS04825-1.pdf?t.download=true&u=5oefqw) is the IRF540 datasheet. Fig 1 on page 3 shows typical results with various Vgs values. You'll see that the lowest value they use is Vgs=5V. The spacing between the 6v and 5V curves suggests that below 5V the results fall quite rapidly. Fig 2 suggests that at Vgs = 4.8V the Rds will be over one Ohm - far from ideal. ...

Comment: ... As others have noted, a lower Vgs_th FET would be a good idea. || Is the breadboard and soldered FET the same device - variations between devices can be critical in this borderline case. || Ass a reverse zener gate to source mounted close to the FET. Zener voltage slightly above Vdrive_max. This clamps Miller capacitance coupled spikes from the drain and can be a (FET) lifesaver in unexpected situations.

Comment: As Neil wrote, a MOSFET is not "triggered". It's like turning on a tap, the threshold voltage is where water just starts to drip out. The datasheet quotes the threshold voltage at a drain current of 250 microamps, you want to to pass nearly 7000 times that much.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon thank you for clearing the doubt. And sorry to the Neil_UK if sounded rude.

Comment: So can I conclude that the MOSFET is not fully triggered in my case? And can you please tell me how you calculated the Rds on-state resistance to be over 1 ohm because I was going according to the rated Rds of 0.028 ohm.

Comment: and one more doubt I have is that on the breadboard the same IRF540 was working perfectly fine and even I triggered the solenoid valve around 10-20 times using the same setup. So why when the valve was connected to our clg toilet pipe the setup didn't work. I might have asked many questions but sorry for it.

Comment: @Meet_1605  Q1: Was it the identical MOSFET in both circuits or were two different ones used?  Q2: What is the voltage across the MOSFET drain-source when it is being driven on?  || The Rdson advertised is a typical value when the MOSFET is fully enhanced (turned on). It is difficult to determine under your conditions as they are at or below the lower level recommended by the manufacturer.

Comment: See fig  7 in [this datasheet.](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/IRF540N.pdf) . At 4 V Vgs the FET supports ~~= 4A at Vdd = 15V in a pulsed test at 25 degrees C. As it heats the results will get better. In the above conditions RDSon = Vds/Ids = 15 V / 4A = 3.75 ohm (!!!). At Vgs=5V it supports 30A at 15V for Rdson = 0.5 Ohm. These are typical results and yours lies somewhere between (probably) The result that I gave yesterday was from a different datasheet and was guesstimated as it was below the provided curves. This FET is "too close to the line" for safety.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon A1. both the MOSFETs were the same (IRF540) which I used in the breadboard and on PCB. A2. I actually forget to measure the Vds during on state sry for that.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon yes this MOSFET is on the borderline of the expected characteristics. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Meet_1605 For interest - it would be useful to clarify one point. You have noted that an IRF540 was used in both circuits. What I was trying to establish was "Was it the same physical IRF540 in both cases?" - ie was the F ET taken out of the breadboard and soldered into the new circuit, or was a different FET used in the 2nd case. The point of this question is IF a physically different FET was used it would not be surprising if the spread of characteristics between devices made a difference. If it was the exact same device then some small change in layout probably made the difference.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon No same FET was installed. and yes have to check the pcb layout again.

Comment: @Meet_1605 When the design is marginal  the difference between working and failure can be as little a capacitance or inductance in wiring, or shared current paths, or other spurious effects.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an Arduino 5V model such as UNO or Nano operating at 5V; Looking at the Fairchild IRF540N should work fine but it is not the best choice. It is an avalanche rated device and it will quench the flyback from your solenoid (see fig 6) so a flyback diode would not be needed. Place something in the 10K range from the output pin of the arduino to ground (this keeps it off after reset until setup(). Connect the pin to the gate wit a 25-50 Ohm resistor and you should be good to go assuming the Source of the MOSFET is also connected to the Arduino ground. If you are using a 3.5V Arduino pick another MOSFET.

Here is a link to the data sheet: https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/IRF540N.pdf

Comment: thanks for your answer, and yes I have already connected the pull-down resistor of 10k ohms at the output pin of the Arduino.